# May expose internal static state by storing a mutable object into a static field

Tags: java, interface, static-methods

There is some legacy code.. The class A has a static field, and a static method in which it's nesessary to assign a value to a static variable. spotbugs advises to store a copy of the object, not the object itself.
But what if the variable type being assigned is an interface?

Calling a static method of class A comes from the constructor of class C

```
public class A {

  private static SomeInterface someInterface;

  public static void setSomeInterface(SomeInterface someInterface) {
        A.someInterface = someInterface;
    }

}
```

```
public interface SomeInterface { 

  ...

}
```

```
public class B implements SomeInterface {

  ...

}
```

```
public class C { 

  public C(final SomeInterface someInterface) {

    A.setSomeInterface(someInterface);

  }

}
```

If it were a class rather than an interface, I could instantiate the object and assign the value of the reference to it, but the input parameter is the interface.

I tried to mark the static method with synchronized, but the bug is still there.
I tried to implement interfaces cloneable and override the clone method in class B also, but i think this is not good idea.

```
public class A {

  private static SomeInterface someInterface;

  public static void setSomeInterface(SomeInterface someInterface) {
        A.someInterface = someInterface.makeClone();
    }

}
```

```
public interface SomeInterface { 

  ...

  SomeInterface  makeClone();

}
```

```
public class B implements SomeInterface, Clonable {

  ...

  @Override
  public SomeInterface makeClone() {
      return clone();
  }

  @Override
  public B clone() {
      try {
          return (B) super.clone();
      } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
          throw new AssertionError();
      }
  }

}
```

What would you advise?

Comment: The object you store in there is not 'an interface'. The __variable type__ is, but an object obviously cannot possibly be (`new SomeInterface()` is not legal java). The mutable state-ness of an object and 'its type implements at least one interface' are completely unrelated. The warning is fair, you should heed it or intentionally choose to ignore it. "It implements an interface" is entirely irrelevant.